Liquid is blocked by something. what should I do?
I'm doing a liquid simulation in Blender. The water is supposed to flow through a pipe, but it seems to be blocked by something in a diagonal direction and is overflowing instead of continuing to flow. What could be wrong, and what should I fix?


Does this cylinder effector have a wall thickness? Is the mesh manifold? If not, you should check the Is Planar option. Apart from that, why do you have set a Surface Thickness of 0.5? I can only guess the dimensions of the objects, but such a thickness makes me think there is not much space inside the cylinder for the fluid, although it seems to touch the surface. How large are these objects? Maybe it would be best to upload your file, because in my own test it works as supposed.

Thx. it solved. I changed the thickess and mesh option.
